# adb android device unauthorized defective screen

Tags: android, adb, platform-tools

I own Galaxy A52 And my screen just stopped working meaning I can't see or touch anything. I'm trying to unlock my phone through my laptop. I just downloaded android platform-tools and installed Samsung Android USB Driver for Windows v1.7.59 followed this guide https://drfone.wondershare.com/android/access-android-phone-with-broken-screen.html?keywords=juego&gclid=CjwKCAiAxvGfBhB-EiwAMPakqleqYpQgBIG382kyeiHbvwhE98C3bFNIw3TqKGyyXVPCQGS3ZqzRfBoCy-AQAvD_BwE
(Part 2)

when I type adb devices
it returns:

`List of devices attached R5CR40WNZDM     unauthorized`

and when I try to go on to the next step And type:
ADB shell input text

it returns

`adb.exe: device unauthorized. This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.`

Is there anything I can do? I'm pretty sure the phone is somehow on airplane mode cause I don't get any notifications and calls but I have an alarm that plays everyday. because of that I can't use SmartThingsFind so.. any other ideas or salutions?

I'm pretty sure the phone is somehow on airplane mode cause I don't get any notifications and calls but I have an alarm that plays everyday. because of that I can't use SmartThingsFind so.. any other ideas or salutions? by the way USB debugging is on

Comment: "Unauthorized" means you have not accepted the dialog that pops up when you try to establish a connection via adb. Without screen and touch it is pretty hard to accept this dialog. The only way would be to connect an USB keyboard, use it (blindly) to pair a Bluetooth keyboard and then use the Bluetooth keyboard to accept the dialog. For more details see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen